# Trying to make a sign up form, but I get a error of Property 'address' does not exist on type 'SignupComponent'? And many more like it

Tags: html, angular, forms

I tried looking up at the issue but, it seems like I am doing it right?
So my HTML content shows that

```
<label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" [(ngModel)]="email" required>

    <label for="username"><b>User Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" [(ngModel)]="username" required>

    <label for="firstname"><b>First Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" [(ngModel)]="firstname" required>

    <label for="lastname"><b>Last Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" [(ngModel)]="lastname" required>
```

I have errors running through my HTML
**Error occurs in the template of component SignupComponent.**
and each of them says
**Property 'lastname' does not exist on type 'SignupComponent'.**

Comment: You need to declare all the property as variable which you have mentioned in your ngModel  your component class.

Comment: And i recommend to use Reactive Forms instead of Template driven form , ngModel I think currently is deprecated